# ReferenceError: message is not defined when trying to make a discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");


const bot = new Discord.Client();

let prefix="!"

bot.on("ready", () => {
  bot.user.setStatus("idle");
console.log(`Demon Is Online`)


bot.on("ready", guild =>  {
bot.user.setActivity("!help | residing on " + bot.guilds.size + " Servers", ); 


bot.on("message", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let command = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);

   if(!command.startsWith(prefix)) return;


    if(command === `${prefix}userinfo`) {
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username)
        .setColor("#3498db")
        .setThumbnail( `${message.author.avatarURL}`)
        .addField("Name", `${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
        .addField("ID", message.author.id)
        message.reply("I've Sent Your User Info Through DM! ")
        message.channel.send({embed}); 
    }}); 
});

    if(command === `${prefix}help`) {
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .addField("!help", "gives you this current information")
        .setTitle("Help")
        .setColor("#3498db")
        .addField("!userinfo", "gives you info about a user(currently being worked on)")
        .addField("!serverinfo","gives you info about a server(currently working on it)") 
        .addField("link to support server","https://discord.gg/NZ2Zvjm")
        .addField("invite link for bot","https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=449983742224760853&permissions=84993&scope=bot")


  message.reply("here's a list of commands that i'm able to do")
        message.channel.send({embed});
    }});
});
  funtion
    messageArray = message.content.split("");
    let command = messageArray[0];
        if(command === `${prefix}serverinfo`) {
            let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(message.author.username)
            .setColor("#3498db")
            .addField("Name", `${message.guild.name}`)
            .addField("Owner", `${message.guild.owner.user}`)
            .addField("Server ID" , message.guild.id)
            .addField("User Count", `${message.guild.members.filter(m => m.presence.status !== 'offline').size} / ${message.guild.memberCount}`)
            .addField("Roles", `${message.guild.roles.size}`);


            message.channel.send({embed});
         } 
        }
     });

bot.login("token goes here")
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvUiM.png)**I was trying to fix my code but while doing so I messed it up and I'm still a noob/beginner at coding so ill show you my errors and output and code and hopefully someone can help me before I decided to post my question on here I asked servers on discord without getting much help basically but basically to learn how to code which I'm trying with code academy but anyways here we go**

Comment: You have a few syntax errors in your code - you might want to fix those first

Comment: basicaly, when you open curly braces, you must close them, same for parenthesis , you are missing a bunch of `});`, your bot.on events listeners mus look like this for example : `bot.on("","", {` **...**  `});` try correcting your indentation to find out where you are missing, and is your launch your code on your browser devlopper tools, you will see where your syntax errors are

Comment: okay I got my bot back online @Neil but the commands wont work ill update what I did

Comment: wow there are a lot of other problem now that i look some more, you were missing closig brackets, but you also have too much in some places in your code, also i can see the word **funtion** isn't there a typo here ? the code after seems messed up, correcting you syntax (block by block to be sure) is the first step, then we can see what you want your bot to do

Comment: https://hastebin.com/witojeqoro.js i got rid of funtion too